# Remove URL tail and leave only domain

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a script to which I am sending a list of links. How can I remove url tail and leave only domain? For example: instead of google.com/adwords, leave only google.com.

```
<form method='post'>
<textarea name="url1" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<input name="Submit" type='submit' value='Send'>
</form>

<?php
$array = explode("\r\n", $_POST['url1']);
$word_count = (array_count_values($array));
arsort($word_count);
foreach ($word_count as $key=>$val) {
echo '<a href="' . $key . '">' . $key . '</a> - ' . $val . '<br/>'; 
}
?>
```

I tried something like:

```
$string = array('https://google.com/ytrewq', 'https://google.com/qwerty'); 
$pattern = '/[^/]+$/';
$replacement = "replacement";
print_r (preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string));
print_r (preg_grep($pattern, $string));
print_r (preg_filter($pattern, $replacement, $string)); 
print_r (preg_match($pattern,$string,$found));
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
// for a single URL:
function getBaseUrl( $url, $includeScheme = false )
{
    $host = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST );
    if ( !$includeScheme ) {
        return $host;
    }

    $scheme = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME );
    return sprintf( '%s://%s', $scheme, $host );
}

$url = 'https://google.com/adwords';
echo getBaseUrl( $url ); // prints 'google.com'
echo getBaseUrl( $url, true ); // prints 'https://google.com'

// for an array of URLs:
function getBaseUrls( $urls, $includeScheme = false )
{
    $baseUrls = [];
    foreach ( $urls as $url ) {
        $baseUrls[] = getBaseUrl( $url, $includeScheme );
    }

    return $baseUrls;
}

$urls = [
    'https://google.com/ytrewq', 
    'https://google.com/qwerty'
];
print_r( getBaseUrls( $urls, true ) );
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php for more information.

Comment: It dont work with array in my code. Or need use "foreach" for array?

Comment: I will add something for arrays to the answer.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a function for arrays

Comment: When I copy\paste this code - server answer 500 http error :(

Comment: What PHP version are you using? I ajusted it so it will also work on PHP versions below 7.

Comment: You're right. I tried the server with php 7.0 and the 500 error is gone. But now the error is displayed in line 24 which comes after $includeScheme):
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'